# Saben por qué un servicio de windows(personalizado c#) se detiene por si solo?

Tags: c#, windows, servicio, net

este es mi tema, tengo un servidor con Windows Server 2016 Standar 64 bits, en el cual ya tenía instalado un servicio de windows desarrollado con c# para .net4 (El cual también ya se encuentra instalado el server), estaba funcionando normal, lo que hace es copiar archivos(Excel) de un compartido al equipo local(Server), solo de momento empezo a fallar, lo que hace es que copia los primeros dos archivos y despues se detiene por si solo el servicio, ya agregué codigo de try catch para validar que no haya algún tipo de error pero no me arroja ningun error. Ademas de que este servicio ya tenía mas de 1 año funcionando sin problema. No son temas del compartido porque si esta fuera el caso entonces no no podría copiar los primeros 2 archivos y no es tema del aplicativo ya que cuando lo corro en una maquina con windows 11 pro(Mi PC), el servicio realiza todo el proceso de copiado completo. Alguien sabe por donde mas puedo buscar? tambien ejecuté el comando: sc query "name_service" en el servidor y me devuelve Win32_exit_code: 1067. Cualquier comentario se los agradezdo mucho.

Agregué código try catch pero no hay error.
Veo el log en el visor de eventos pero no hay nada de porque se esta deteniendo.

Comment: Cuando dices "agregue /try/catch no me arroja".... estas guardando en disco el log? tendrias que tener un archivo de log para estos "inconvenientes", es decir el catch deberia guardar en un archivo... para esto recomendacion utilizar componente de log como [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) para saber exactamente si hay un error saber porque se detuvo. En el visor de eventos solo veras algo que el sistema operativo detecte y puede ser que tu app no escriba por lo que comentas en dicho Visor de Eventos. Por eso coloca el log, escribe en disco ese log y copia aqui el error que te arroja ahi.

Comment: Hola Jose, ya estoy enviando la información a un .txt en el disco local como sugieres, de echo no se ven excepciones de código, el proceso solo se detiene, y esta raro porque de echo hace la copia de dos archivos al inicio y cuando va por el tercero se detiene, podría ser que algo del SO le este afectando?

Comment: Luis, puede ser que el servicio este ejecutando con un usuario (Network Service por default). SI ejecutaste en tu maquina lo hiciste con otro usuario (eso es la primera diferencia). Lo otro, que es "dificil" de debugear un servicio de windows. Te puedo dar una alternativa o recomendacion "que a mi me sirvio hace mas de 15 años", en vez de usar servicios de windows migre e una app de consola que se ejecuta como [Tarea Programada](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/schedule), puedes probar mas facilmente y ejecutar en el servidor de forma aislada

Comment: Encontré esta información en el visor de eventos --> Vistas personalizadas --> Eventos administr: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM 
Server application with CLSID {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160} and APPID {9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
to the user MiDominio\MiUsuario SID (S-1-5-21-47451956-287255056-273882866-131803) from address LocalHost 
(Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). 
This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: El servicio utiliza las credenciales User: MiDominio\MiUsuario, Password: Mi Passowrd pero sigue marcando el mismo
error de arriba, también realice la configuración que encontre 
aquí(https://therefore.net/help/2022/en-us/ins_connectivity_dcom_2016.html) pero sigue marcando el mismo 
error.

Comment: Estimado Luis, el error es muy especifico (tendrias que agregar el mensaje del visor a tu descripcion en la pregunta para completarla por favor, asi cuando la leemos la primera vez esta con dicho mensaje).

Comment: Busque el identificador "D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160" en  SO "english" y [encontre esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669672/the-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permi/64673895#64673895) Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia porque el error es muy especifico de "permisos" como indica pero sobre un componente DCOM que es el "identificador" que envias.